# How do I install Aircrack on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I would like to know how to install Aircrack on Ubuntu 16.04. Please provide detailed guidance on all the steps needed. Also, could you provide the link where I can download the latest version of Aircrack?

Comment: `sudo apt install aircrack-ng`

Comment: Non capisco cosa volete dirmi... Potresti darmi una risposto esauriente LER favore?

Comment: We only support english

Comment: Run in terminal the command I posted it the first comment and that's it.

Comment: I don't get why you posted in Italian, but if you don't like English you can always use the *Chiedi* platform of the Ubuntu-it community. http://chiedi.ubuntu-it.org/

Answer (score 6):

> I want to know how to install aircrack ubuntu 16.04 Describe me in a detailed and meticulous manners in each step.

That is simple. To install ...

```
 sudo apt install aircrack-ng
```

In 16.04 this will install `aircrack-ng 1:1.2-0~beta3-4`. The latest is 1.2 RC 4 so we are not too far off from the latest.

> I would also link to download the latest version of aircrack

See their website: https://www.aircrack-ng.org/

Ubuntu is not about installing the newest software and randomly downloading software from the web is not the method we use. We use the stable version of software as it was at the time of release of that version of Ubuntu.

Be aware that downloading from a random website also means you need to scan that software for malicious content yourself.

Comment: Now the latest version is in Ubuntu repos.

Comment: Hmmmm I think we miss a release canditate(3.4 versus 4.0)

Comment: Maybe you are right, but I do not think it matters much. And I am not sure that `beta3-4` is not the same as `rc4`. ;-)